# Winforms how to make two user controls work simultaneously by triggering either of them

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

Using Winforms I have created a user control with two buttons, one label and one browsable property.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "Button1 is clicked";
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "Button2 is clicked";
    }

    public enum Type { StandAlone = 1, Parallel }
    private Type _defaultType = Type.StandAlone;

    [Browsable(true), DisplayName("Type")]
    public Type MyProperty { get { return _defaultType; } set { _defaultType = value; } }
```

Now I have added 4 of these to my forms.

What I am expecting to do is if the user selects Parallel for two of these user controls, then those two should work simultaneously.

Let us say the 4 user controls are named ucControl1, ucControl2, ucControl3, ucControl4

If the Type property of ucControl1 and ucControl2 are set to parallel, then on runtime if user clicks button1 of ucControl1, then button1 of ucControl2 also should get the Click event triggered and vice-versa.

Is this possible? What are my options?

Comment: So, something like the [PerformAutoUpdate](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/RadioButton.cs,494) procedure of RadioButtons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could cheat and keep a `static` list of UserControls within the UserControl itself.  Add each UserControl to the list from its Constructor.  Then you can iterate over that and ask each parallel UserControl to click the button of the same name.

You have to do some extra housekeeping to keep the buttons from infinitely clicking each other.  Here's a quick example:

```
public partial class ucControl : UserControl
{

    private static bool suppressRecursion = false;
    private static List<ucControl> ucControls = new List<ucControl>();

    public ucControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ucControls.Add(this);
        button1.Click += (s, e) => ClickParallelButtons((Button)s);
        button2.Click += (s, e) => ClickParallelButtons((Button)s);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("button1 of " + this.Name + " clicked.");            
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("button2 of " + this.Name + " clicked.");
    }

    private void ClickParallelButtons(Button btn)
    {
        if (this._defaultType == Type.Parallel && !suppressRecursion)
        {
            suppressRecursion = true;
            foreach (ucControl uc in ucControls)
            {
                if (uc != this && uc._defaultType == Type.Parallel)
                {
                    Control ctlTarget = uc.Controls.Find(btn.Name, true).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (ctlTarget != null && ctlTarget is Button)
                    {
                        ((Button)ctlTarget).PerformClick();
                    }
                }
            }
            suppressRecursion = false;
        }            
    }

    public enum Type { StandAlone = 1, Parallel }
    private Type _defaultType = Type.StandAlone;

    [Browsable(true), DisplayName("Type")]
    public Type MyProperty { get { return _defaultType; } set { _defaultType = value; } }

}
```